# Finding the coordinates of a point contained by a trapezoid programmatically

Tags: math, language-agnostic

If I have a trapezoid defined by four points  (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4) *(chosen as (255, 0), (255, 235), (200, 35), and (200, 235) for the sake of the example)*, and I divide it arbitrarily in **n** by **m** sections like so (pardon the crude drawing):

[image: plane]

How could I find the coordinates of (x, y)?

I've tried fooling around with the slopes of the lines, but my math skills are too rusty to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Will the trapezoid always be oriented vertically like in your example or can it be rotated arbitrarily?

Comment: @slebetman Edges on the Y-axis will always be parallel

Comment: You do not give enough information to solve this problem. What parameters are known to define the position of the red dot in the trapezoid? How are the sections spread over the trapezoid? Do you want to achieve a perspective projection?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe The shape is divided in n by m sections. The red dot could be considered the ith horizontal division by the jth vertical division, or (x,y) in my case.  I think that's enough information?  Given x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, horizontalSegments, verticalSegments, desiredHorizontalSegment, desiredVerticalSegment, find the intersection of the lines connecting the desiredHorizontalSegment and the desiredVerticalSegment.  Just as slebetman showed in his answer.

Comment: I posted the comment because I felt that your question looks like being of general use and having a commonly applicable solution. After reading the comments and @slebetman's answer it becomes clear, though, that you are after a very special result for a narrow use case. I, for instance, thought you want to calculate a point on a plane in a perspective projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific case as per your example it's quite straight forward.

First, the x location is easy. Since the verticals will always be parallel to the y axis, x is simply x width divided by the number of sections:

```
x = x1+((x2-x1)/a*xa)
```

where:

- x = result coordinate
- x1,x2 = edges of the trapezoid
- a = number of sections
- xa = x coordinate in term of sections

note: I chose `a` to avoid confusion with the symbol for slope: `m`.

For y it's a bit more complicated. We first need to find the coordinate that sits on the top and bottom lines of the trapezoid. We use the standard line equation for this:

```
y = mx+c
```

Finding m is simple. It's just Dy/Dx:

```
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

To get c we just substitute x, y and m into the formula:

```
c = y-mx
```

Once we get that, substitute the value of x found earlier into the formula to get the y coordinate. Do this twice to get the points on the top and bottom lines:

```
    1            A              2
    x------------x--------------x
    |            |              |
    |            xC             |
    |            |              |
    x------------x--------------x
    3            B              4
```

All together (pseudocode):

```
coordinateFromSection (x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4 gridX gridY sectionX sectionY) {

    xC = x1+((x2-x1)/gridX*sectionX)

    // top line:
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    c = y1-(m*x1)
    yA = m*xC + c

    // bottom line:
    m = (y4-y3)/(x4-x3)
    c = y3-(m*x3)
    yB = m*xC + c

    // Find yC by dividing line AB by gridY
    yC = yA+((yB-yA)/gridY*sectionY)

    return (xC yC)
}
```

All the calculations above assume that (0,0) is the top left of the screen.